# Yeoman npminstall is installing old packages

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Though I've published a new version of one of dependent library but when I am installing that using the yeoman generator it is installing -1 version than the current version. I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: Did you check the content of the generated `package.json` file? Yeoman doesn't any magic, it just runs npm. So npm will install whatever is defined in that file.

Comment: Yes. The problem may be due to the new npm version. Where the npm is not managing versions properly. I haven't mentioned anything in the generator `index.js` but somehow it is installing previous version not the current version. I have raised an issue in npm's github.